# Creating jsonwebtoken to authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with back end part in my app and I hope you will help me. I'm new in in back-end.
I made Express server in server.js and connected MongoDB. After that I required jwt and add createAccessToken and createRefreshToken in userCtrl.js and I checked in postman if it become requests. With access token with POST request I have not problem, but when I began to add refresh token, in the postman it hasn't authorization. Can I become some help. I don't know where is wrong.

I put my code :

**userRouter.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const userCtrl = require('../controlleers/userCtrl')

router.post('/register', userCtrl.register)

router.get('/refresh_token', userCtrl.refreshToken)

module.exports = router
```

**.env**

```
MONGO_URL = ************
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ***********
REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET = **********
```

**userModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },

    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },

    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },

    cart: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
  },

  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema)
```

**userCtrl.js**

```
const Users = require('../models/userModel')

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const userCtrl = {
  register: async (req, res) => {
    // async before a function means one simple thing: a function always returns a promise.

    try {
      const { name, email, password } = req.body

      const user = await Users.findOne({ email }) // wait until the promise resolves

      if (user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'The email already exists' })

      if (password.length < 6) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Password is at least 6 characteres long.' })

      //Password encryption

      const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)

      const newUser = new Users({
        name,
        email,
        password: passwordHash,
      })

      // save mongodb

      await newUser.save()

      //then create jsonwebtoken to authentication

      const accesstoken = createAccessToken({ id: newUser._id })

      const refreshtoken = createRefreshToken({ id: newUser._id })

      res.cookie('refreshtoken', refreshtoken, {
        httpOnly: true,

        path: '/user/refresh_token',
      })

      res.json({ accesstoken })

      //res.json({msg: "Register Success!"})
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message })
    }
  },
  refreshToken: (req, res) => {
    const rf_token = req.cookies.refreshtoken

    res.json({ rf_token })
  },
}
const createAccessToken = (user) => {
  return jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1d' })
}

const createRefreshToken = (user) => {
  return jwt.sign(user, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: '7d' })
}

module.exports = userCtrl
```

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors())

// Use temp files instead of memory for managing the upload process.
app.use(fileUpload({
    useTempFiles: true
}))

// Routes
app.use('/user', require('./routes/userRouter'))

// Connect to Mongodb
const URL = process.env.MONGO_URL
mongoose.connect(URL,{
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, err =>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
})



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port', PORT)
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `router.post('/refresh_token', userCtrl.refreshToken)` ? Since you are doing a HTTP POST ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not exporting `userCtrl` from your controller by the looks of it.

```js
module.exports = {
  userCtrl
}
```

**EDIT**:

Say your user controller looks something like this,

```js
// user.js
const router = require("express").Router();

router.get('/user/refresh_token', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Received request');
  res.send(200);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Ensure your root URL is correct in your server/index JS file.

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const user = require('./user');

/*
  For your use case, ensure `/` is used to mount your user middleware.
  If you use /user here like,
    app.use('/user', user);
  
  Then your GET URL will be /user/user/refresh_token
*/
app.use('/', user); 

app.listen(5000, function() {
  console.log('Server listening on port 5000')
})
```

**EDIT**:

You'll need to update the `Path` parameter when you're setting the cookie to,

```
res.cookie('refreshToken', 'some-random-value', {
  httpOnly: true,
  path: '/user', // even /user/refresh_token should work
});
```

Here's the screenshot of it working on my local for both these Paths.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I have it , just forgot to add here in code. I edited it

Comment: @nik_kolev and you've instantiated the router in your `server.js` file too?

Comment: I was wrong URL . It was /user/user/refresh_token and I changed that to be /user/refresh_token. I added  your get request and the Postman said me "OK" and it works but in cookie I have nothing